# Run "ant test" using android sdk tools v14

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

After upgrading to android sdk tools v14 and updating existing projects to last project structure, `ant test` fails with the error message:

```
test:
    [echo] Running tests ...
    [exec] Syntax error: Bad substitution`
```

Output of `ant -v test`

```
    [echo] Running tests ...
    [exec] Current OS is Mac OS X
    [exec] Executing '/opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools/adb' with arguments:
    [exec] 'shell'
    [exec] 'am'
    [exec] 'instrument'
    [exec] '-w'
    [exec] '-e'
    [exec] 'coverage'
    [exec] 'false'
    [exec] 'xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx'
    [exec] 
    [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [exec] not part of the command.
```

But directly execute command `adb shell am instrument` is fine. 
My environment is Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 on Mac.
Please help.

Comment: Does this show the error -- the next line is "Bad Substitution"?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue of r14 tools. See http://tools.android.com/knownissues

> Testing
>   ant test fails with Syntax error: Bad substitution.
>   A last minute change introduced this error in the Ant rules file. The workaround is to edit /tools/ant/build.xml, line 318 and to change ${manifest.package} with ${tested.manifest.package}. [Issue 20979]